# SIGINT not being captured after using ruby system() command

Tags: ruby, unix, fork, signals

When I ran the ruby code below, pressing ctrl + c would immediately stop the program

```
trap("INT") { exit }
while line = gets; puts line; end
```

However, when I use system() command before the gets, pressing ctrl + c would not take any effect unless I hit "Enter". It seems like it has to do with system() forking a child process and somehow the parent could no longer detect SIGINT. How would you change the code so that ctrl + c would take immediate effect for the code below

```
trap("INT") { exit }

if system("which ruby > /dev/null")
  puts "ruby is installed"
end

while line = gets; puts line; end
```

Comment: I can reproduce this behavior with ruby 1.8.7 on both debian and MacOS.

Comment: im using ruby-1.8.7-p357 on MacOS

Comment: but when i switched to ruby-1.9.2-p290, they both respond the same way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a bug in the signal handling which was fixed in 1.9, to work around your problem, define the signal trap after the system call:

```
if system("which ruby > /dev/null")
  puts "ruby is installed"
end
trap("INT") { p 'Ciao!'; exit }
while line = gets; puts line; end
```

Not ideal, but it works.